# Does Ragnarok Online 2 feature PvP fortress battles?

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

The fortress battles and the ability for a guild to 'own' a castle for a week were my favorite feature of the original Ragnarok.  Are these features in the sequel?

Comment: Worth noting that the game apparently got to beta, then was "unreleased" and largely redone, including revamping the core systems like classes, so this may be subject to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile the new Ragnarok 2 (Legend of the Second) has been opened for a while in Korea and has recently received the War of Emperium update.

You can find a lot of information on the irowiki:
http://forums.irowiki.org/showthread.php?t=102577

Taken from there:

> #### 1. War of Emperium - Start & Duration
>
> War of Emperium is held on every Saturday, 9:00 PM and continues until 10:00 PM KST (Korean Standard Time) for a total of 1 hour. However, since we are in the midst of practice WoE phase, WoE will happen once every 2 days up until May 22th.
> Please note that there will be a system announcement 5 minutes before War of Emperium to signal the players.
>
> Also, Prontera Fortress area will be an open PvP area where members of different guilds may attack each other. There are also monsters that populate the area, so this map can also be used as a hunting ground.
> Defeating monsters in this area will award the player(s) with Honor Points (PvP Point).
>
> #### 2. War of Emperium and Fortification Bases
>
> Once War of Emperium starts, an emperium spawns inside the innermost area of the castle as well as in various fortification bases. The main objective of the attacking guild is to destroy the emperium inside the castle, and defending guild's objective is to prevent this from happening.
>
> There is an emperium present in each fortification bases, and destroying these will provide beneficial buffs to the attacking guild. In order to take advantage of the buff, the attacking guild must first conquer these points.
> When there are multiple guilds attacking an emperium, guild that dealt the most damage to the emperium will assume control over the area.
> Also, the fortification bases can be taken multiple times by other guilds, robbing the previous guild of beneficial buffs once it's taken.

A lot seems to have been taken from the old system:

- Fortress battles only open on set times (currently every Saturday for 1 hour)
- Destroying the emperium grants you the fortress (though this time the guild that does the most damage wins, instead of the guild that had the last hit on it)

There are also some new features:

- Buff system when destroying an emperium
- Usage of siege weapons

> List of Prontera Fortress and Fortification Base buffs:
> Prontera Fortress (Castle) - +1,000 HP and +15% movement speed.
> Marching Fortification Base - +200% HP. Bonus skill: *Lucky Guy*
> Strength Fortification Base - +1,000 Defense rate. Bonus skill: *Half Life*
> Guardian Fortification Base - Nullifies all critical damage. Bonus skill: *Heart Breaker*
> Beneficial buff from Prontera Fortress will persist after War of Emperium.
>
> Bonus skill description:
> Lucky Guy - *Increases caster's critical chance by 10%, and further increases critical chance by another 10% every time a skill lands a critical strike (up to a maximum of 50% total increase).*
> Half Life - *Deals target's 50% maximum life in damage.*
> Heart Breaker - *Deals 5,000 defense piercing damage to a target.*
>
> #### 3. Siege weapons
>
> Utilizing siege weapons strategically will greatly bolster a guild's ability to win the battle.
> Each siege weapons require different amount of siege supplies to use.
> (Siege supplies can also be used to repair Emperium, Doors as well as Siege weapons)
>
> Each player may only carry up to a maximum of 10 Siege supplies. A group effort will be required to keep utilizing the siege weapons or to repair.
>
> There are two types of Siege weapons. These are Mountable Siege Weapons and Controllable Siege Weapons.
>
> **Mountable Siege Weapons**
> Battering Ram: *Uses a skill to deal powerful damage to castle door and objects. (Cannot attack players or monsters)*
> Guardian Statue: *Redirects all siege weapon attacks, except attacks from Ballista.*
> Ghost Palanquin: *Uses a skill to shroud nearby allies in cloaking mode.*
> Defense Statue: *Uses a skill to increase nearby allies' attack, magic attack and movement speed.*
>
> **Controllable Siege Weapons**
> Catapult: *Launches a boulder at a target location to deal large damage to enemies.
> (Catapult can launch at a farther location depending on how long you hold down the launch button)*
> Cannon: *Fires a cannon at a target location to deal damage to enemies.*
> Ballista: *Fire arrows of light at a target location to deal damage to enemies. Pierces 
> Guardian Statue effect.*
> Hwacha: *Fire many arrows at a target location to deal damage to enemies.*
> Mortar: *Fire various status inflicting cannons at a target location.*

Note that at the momentent WoE is still in a very early stage and is still being tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find much on this subject.

I did find a RO2 blog (by a RO2 developer?) that [doesn't say anything definite on the subject](http://ro2lots.blogspot.com/2010/09/ragnarok-pvp.html) but does hope for a system like War of Emperium (WoE)

PVP for RO2 [does exist (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUEfSnyOKog) .